# How to design/write my GlobalConfig class so that can be inherited?

Tags: c#, static, singleton

I need to create a GlobalConfig class. But I want to derive from it in another class.

Here's an example:

```
public class BaseConfig {
    public String GlobalPath {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ConfigA: BaseConfig {
    public String pathA {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ConfigB: ConfigA {
    public String pathB {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The idea behind is that I don't want to write the code multiple times, what more important in class `ConfigA` is, I want to set `GlobalPath` and have access to it in ConfigB.

In other word, I want class `ConfigB` to have a property `GlobalPath` which was set in class `ConfigA`.

To clarify I want to have **only one object of config in memory**.

When I set `BaseConfig.GlobalPath` to "A", I want to access it from `ConfigB.GlobalPath` and also get "A".

I always design `GlobalConfig` as a static class, but static classes cannot be inherited.

So I tried to implement ***singleton pattern***, but `ConfigA` cannot find the constructor of class `BaseConfig` because it's private.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean about the way you want your properties to work? Assuming `BaseConfig` has `GlobalPath` you can get/set it from any of the descendants, it will be the same instance. As to your constructor issue, mark it as `protected` and it's isolated to the class and descendants.

Comment: I'd reconsider the whole design. I'd use different interfaces for different parts of the config, and I'd pass an instance implementing that interface to the parts of the program that need it("push"), instead of using `Config.Instance` or similar "pull" based singletons.